# Unable to authenticate using Angular MSAL library after upgrade to version 3.0.0-beta.0

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, msal-angular

After upgrading my app from `Angular v15` to `v16` and from `msal-angular 2.5.3` to `3.0.0-beta.0`, I am no longer able to authenticate against `Azure AD B2C`. I see the following exception in the console when attempting to execute MSAL `loginPopup()`:

```
app-error-handler.service.ts:24 ERROR BrowserAuthError: native_broker_called_before_initialize:
You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API 
when native brokering is enabled. For more please visit aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors.
```

The MSAL verbose log since the start of the app to the point when `loginPopup()` is called looks like this:

```
[webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement disabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled.
debug.reducer.ts:10 [DEBUG] action: @ngrx/store/init {payload: undefined, oldState: undefined, newState: {…}}
debug.reducer.ts:10 [DEBUG] action: @ngrx/store/update-reducers {payload: undefined, oldState: {…}, newState: {…}}
debug.reducer.ts:10 [DEBUG] action: @ngrx/store-devtools/recompute {payload: undefined, oldState: {…}, newState: {…}}
debug.reducer.ts:10 [DEBUG] action: @ngrx/store-devtools/recompute {payload: undefined, oldState: {…}, newState: {…}}
debug.reducer.ts:10 [DEBUG] action: @ngrx/effects/init {payload: undefined, oldState: {…}, newState: {…}}
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - BrowserCrypto: modern crypto interface available
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - BrowserCrypto: modern crypto interface available
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Event callback registered with id: dd757329-a0a6-4bf8-9d67-11a173a1078e
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - getAllAccounts called
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - BrowserCacheManager.getAccountKeys - No account keys found
debug.reducer.ts:10 [DEBUG] action: @ngrx/router-store/request {payload: {…}, oldState: {…}, newState: {…}}
core.mjs:25489 Angular is running in development mode.
debug.reducer.ts:10 [DEBUG] action: @ngrx/router-store/navigation {payload: {…}, oldState: {…}, newState: {…}}
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:24 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
debug.reducer.ts:10 [DEBUG] action: @ngrx/router-store/navigated {payload: {…}, oldState: {…}, newState: {…}}
2report-config.service.ts:206 updating configViewDS
report-config.service.ts:484 updating searchByNameViewDS with 0 results
report-config.service.ts:368 updating searchByActionViewDS with 0 results
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:25 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:25 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:25 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:25 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:25 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:43:25 GMT] : @azure/msal-angular@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - Interceptor - no scopes for endpoint
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:44:21 GMT] : [7d18b1b4-a4ca-4c5f-8678-849944fa42b4] : @azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - loginPopup called
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:44:21 GMT] : [7d18b1b4-a4ca-4c5f-8678-849944fa42b4] : @azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - acquireTokenPopup called
user-identity.config.ts:54 MSAL logging:  [Sun, 02 Jul 2023 22:44:21 GMT] : @azure/msal-browser@3.0.0-beta.0 : Verbose - preflightBrowserEnvironmentCheck started
app-error-handler.service.ts:24 ERROR BrowserAuthError: native_broker_called_before_initialize: You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API when native brokering is enabled. For more please visit aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors.
    at BrowserAuthError.createNativeBrokerCalledBeforeInitialize (BrowserAuthError.js:478:16)
    at BrowserUtils.blockNativeBrokerCalledBeforeInitialized (BrowserUtils.js:131:36)
    at StandardController.preflightBrowserEnvironmentCheck (StandardController.js:809:26)
    at StandardController.acquireTokenPopup (StandardController.js:290:18)
    at StandardController.loginPopup (StandardController.js:1122:21)
    at PublicClientApplication.loginPopup (PublicClientApplication.js:205:32)
    at MsalService.loginPopup (azure-msal-angular.mjs:55:35)
    at UserIdentityService.login (user-identity.service.ts:94:26)
    at AppComponent.onLoginClick (app.component.ts:111:26)
    at AppComponent_button_29_Template_button_click_0_listener (app.component.html:43:88)
```

I have read through [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/errors.md), but I am not sure if this is applicable since I am using `Popup` interaction as opposed to `redirect`.

Any suggestion on how to go about fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Upgrading from MSAL Angular v2 to v3](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/v2-v3-upgrade-guide.md#the-allownativebroker-flag) :

> ### The allowNativeBroker flag
>
> The allowNativeBroker flag is now turned on
> by default in the configurations. If you're using a B2C authority you
> can turn it off as follows:
>
> ```
> export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
>     return new PublicClientApplication({
>         auth: {
>             ...
>         },
>         cache: {
>             ...
>         },
>         system: {
>             allowNativeBroker: false, // Disables native brokering support
>         }
>     });
> }
> ```

Comment: Setting `allowNativeBroker` to `false` appears to have resolved my issue described above. Thanks! However, the `Upgrading` document you referred to also says I should also `either bootstrap the MsalRedirectComponent or call handleRedirectObservable manually` even though I use the `Popup` flow. I have not done that, but my app now seems to work the way it did before the `3.0` upgrade. Should I do the `MsalRedirectComponent` bootstrap as well?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know enough about how the library works to recommend one way or another.